# How to write a QuerySet using F expressions on a related model's FK field in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, jquery-ui-autocomplete, django-filters

In my **autocomplete** function I am using the following query expression to get the model field value:

```
def CitySearch(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term','')
        names = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).annotate(value=F('name'), label=F('name')).values('id', 'value', 'label')

    ...
    ...
    return HttpResponse.....
```

**How do I filter the (model) `City` field "`name`" to the FK field of related model "`Country`"?**

Comment: Do you mean inner join? Can you elaborate on your requirements?

Comment: That's right. I am using the function for jQuery autocomplete and trying to filter out the country field values not in both City (the model I am trying to build the QuerySet for) to the related model "Country" through the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following guessing country has a name field.

```
 names = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).annotate(value=F('name'), label=F('name')).values('id', 'value', 'label', 'country__name')
```

Or you can do,

```
 names = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).annotate(value=F('name'), country_name=F('country__name'), label=F('name')).values('id', 'value', 'label', 'country_name')
```

Comment: Model "Country" has the FK field defined as `name`. However, with both alternatives I am getting error `ValueError: The annotation 'country' conflicts with a field on the model`.

Comment: I updated the answer. hope it will help. You just need to name the field other than the country.

Comment: Does it fix the issue?

Comment: I am sorry, but no. Though this time there are no errors, but the filter is not working.

Comment: Are you extracting value like this? `.values('id', 'value', 'label', 'country_name')`

Comment: No. Doing it like this: `.values('id', 'value', 'label', 'country__name')`. Doing it using `.values('id', 'value', 'label', 'country_name')` is resulting in error.

Comment: It should also work. `names = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=q).annotate(value=F('name'), country_name=F('country__name'), label=F('name')).values('id', 'value', 'label', 'country_name')`

Comment: This was the 2nd one (of your answer), already tried. Filter not happening.